# Extracting Sub-Trees Using Stanford Tregex

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have made a class to extract subtrees using Tregex. I used some code snips from "TregexPattern.java", as i don't want to let the program use the console commands.

In general, having a tree for a sentence, I want to extract certain sub tree (no user interaction).

what I did so far is the following:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.StringLabelFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public abstract class Test {
    abstract TregexMatcher matcher(Tree root, Tree tree, Map<String, Tree> namesToNodes, VariableStrings variableStrings);
    public TregexMatcher matcher(Tree t) {
        return matcher(t, t, new HashMap<String, Tree>(), new VariableStrings());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        TregexPattern p = TregexPattern.compile("NP < NN & <<DT"); //"/^MWV/" or "NP < (NP=np < NNS)"
        TreeReader r = new PennTreeReader(new StringReader("(VP (VP (VBZ Try) (NP (NP (DT this) (NN wine)) (CC and) (NP (DT these) (NNS snails)))) (PUNCT .))"), new LabeledScoredTreeFactory(new StringLabelFactory()));
        Tree t = r.readTree();
        treebank = new MemoryTreebank();
        treebank.add(t);
        TRegexTreeVisitor vis = new TRegexTreeVisitor(p, encoding);
        **treebank.apply(vis);  //line 26**
        if (TRegexTreeVisitor.printMatches) {
            System.out.println("There were " + vis.numMatches() + " matches in total.");
        }
    }
    private static Treebank treebank; // used by main method, must be accessible
    static class TRegexTreeVisitor implements TreeVisitor {
        private static boolean printNumMatchesToStdOut = false;
        static boolean printNonMatchingTrees = false;
        static boolean printSubtreeCode = false;
        static boolean printTree = false;
        static boolean printWholeTree = false;
        static boolean printMatches = true;
        static boolean printFilename = false;
        static boolean oneMatchPerRootNode = false;
        static boolean reportTreeNumbers = false;
        static TreePrint tp;
        PrintWriter pw;
        int treeNumber = 0;
        TregexPattern p;
        //String[] handles;
        int numMatches;
        TRegexTreeVisitor(TregexPattern p, String encoding) {
            this.p = p;
            //this.handles = handles;
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, encoding), true);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.err.println("Error -- encoding " + encoding + " is unsupported.  Using ASCII print writer instead.");
                pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
            }
            // tp.setPrintWriter(pw);
        }
        public void visitTree(Tree t) {
            treeNumber++;
            if (printTree) {
                pw.print(treeNumber + ":");
                pw.println("Next tree read:");
                tp.printTree(t, pw);
            }
            TregexMatcher match = p.matcher(t);
            if (printNonMatchingTrees) {
                if (match.find()) {
                    numMatches++;
                } else {
                    tp.printTree(t, pw);
                }
                return;
            }
            Tree lastMatchingRootNode = null;
            while (match.find()) {
                if (oneMatchPerRootNode) {
                    if (lastMatchingRootNode == match.getMatch()) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        lastMatchingRootNode = match.getMatch();
                    }
                }
                numMatches++;
                if (printFilename && treebank instanceof DiskTreebank) {
                    DiskTreebank dtb = (DiskTreebank) treebank;
                    pw.print("# ");
                    pw.println(dtb.getCurrentFile());
                }
                if (printSubtreeCode) {
                    pw.println(treeNumber + ":" + match.getMatch().nodeNumber(t));
                }
                if (printMatches) {
                    if (reportTreeNumbers) {
                        pw.print(treeNumber + ": ");
                    }
                    if (printTree) {
                        pw.println("Found a full match:");
                    }
                    if (printWholeTree) {
                        tp.printTree(t, pw);
                    } else {
                        **tp.printTree(match.getMatch(), pw);  //line 108**
                    }
                    // pw.println();  // TreePrint already puts a blank line in
                } // end if (printMatches)
            } // end while match.find()
        } // end visitTree
        public int numMatches() {
            return numMatches;
        }
    } // end class TRegexTreeVisitor
}
```

but it give the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.Test$TRegexTreeVisitor.visitTree(Test.java:108)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.MemoryTreebank.apply(MemoryTreebank.java:376)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.Test.main(Test.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Any modifications or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException is usually an indicator of bug in software.

I had the same task in the past. Sentence was parsed with dependency parser. 
I decided to put resulting parse tree in XML(DOM) and perform XPath queries over it.

To enhance performance you don't need to put xml in String, just keep all XML structure as DOM in memory (e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-domjava/).

Using XPath for querying tree-like data structure gave me the following benefits:

1. **Load/Save/Transfer results of sentence parsing easily.**
2. Robust syntax/capabilities of XPath.
3. Many people know XPath (everyone can customize your query).
4. XML and XPath are cross platform.
5. Plenty of stable implementations of XPath and XML/DOM libraries.
6. Ability to use XSLT.
7. Integration with existing XML-based pipeline **XSLT+XPath -> XSD -> Do actions** *(e.g. users have specified their email address and action what to do with it somewhere inside of free-text complaint)*.